# JSF Datatable row manipulation

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6

I am wondering the best way to solve this problem.

I have a datatable with two buttons (Edit and Delete) with details something like below:

First Name  Last Name   ...etc 
John        Doe             Edit | Delete 
Jane        Doe             Edit | Delete

I want to make it so when the Edit button is clicked, A Save button that is hidden replaces the edit button and makes all the outputText fields become a input text on that row.

e.g. Changes to after the first line is clicked.

First Name  Last Name   ...etc 
John        Doe             Save | Delete
Jane        Doe             Edit | Delete

Any other ideas on a better design would also be acceptable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PrimeFaces's [datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf).